# How to access the backend files on my instance in google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, magento

I have installed Magento using Google Cloud Platform's (One-Click Deployment) However, I don't know how to access these files on the server. There is no file manager or anyway to access server files.
I'm using Google Compute Engine. And I connected to the server using Filezilla, But It seems like there is no Magento installation there, It's all server files and stuff like that.

Comment: This one? https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/click-to-deploy-images/magento Try looking in `/var/www`.

Comment: Ok, Sorry.. Yes I found it there, whooo.. Thank you..

Comment: To add visibility I would suggest posting an answer.

Comment: @Carlos IMO, "where are my files on this particular image" isn't particularly helpful to other users, which is why I answered in a comment. Folks on ServerFault are generally expected to know what's configured and where on their boxes already.